# How do I secure an AWS API Gateway with Cognito?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I've setup an Identity pool and using Python and boto3 I'm able to retrieve an access key, secret key and session token, which I assume is for an unauthenticated user:

```
import boto3
boto3.setup_default_session(region_name='us-east-1')
identity = boto3.client('cognito-identity', 
                        region_name='us-east-1')

response = identity.get_id(AccountId='12344566', IdentityPoolId='us-east-1:XXXXXX')
identity_id = response['IdentityId']
print ("Identity ID: %s"%identity_id)

response = identity.get_open_id_token(IdentityId=identity_id)
token = response['Token']
print ("\nToken: %s"%(token))

resp = identity.get_credentials_for_identity(IdentityId=identity_id)
secretKey = resp['Credentials']['SecretKey']
accessKey = resp['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']

print ("\nSecret Key: %s"%(secretKey))
print ("\nAccess Key %s"%(accessKey))
```

Once I have these details I'm then attempting to call the API Gateway. I use javascript for this task as I haven't found an easy way to achieve the result I want in python:

```
var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
  accessKey: 'aaaaaaaa',
  secretKey: 'kkkkkkkk',
  sessionToken: 'ssssss',
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

  apigClient.helloworldGet({},'')
  .then(function(result){
      console.log("success!: " + result);
    }).catch( function(result){
      console.log("FAIL: " + result);
    });
```

This fails with the response:

```
   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403

.
```

I've setup CORS correctly as the OPTIONS request succeeds. If I use my main access key and secret to authenticate the script works. If I turn off the IAM credentials requirement on the get/helloworld method the javascript runs successfully. I've attached a policy to both the auth and unauth roles that Cognito setup for the identity pool, this policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "dsfdsafasfdsfasdf",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456787:dsfsdfsdfs/dev/GET/helloworld"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried attaching this both as a managed policy and an inline policy.

What am I missing here? Is it something to do with trying to access as an unauthenticated user (even though the role assigned to that type of user has a policy attached that should allow it to access the API)?

Note that there's no Lamda's involved here, just a simple task definition sitting in an ECS Autoscale group that the API Gateway calls when the helloworld method is invoked. As detailed here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-with-microservices-deployed-on-amazon-ecs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the way I was retrieving the token. I was using

```
sessionToken = identity.get_open_id_token(IdentityId=identity_id)
```

I should have got the token from the response when I requested credentials:

```
resp = identity.get_credentials_for_identity(IdentityId=identity_id)
secretKey = resp['Credentials']['SecretKey']
accessKey = resp['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
sessionToken = resp['Credentials']['SessionToken']
```